# Examples of functions in generalized linear models

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family

Let $X \in {R}^{n\times p}, Y \in R^{n}$ and $\beta \in R^p$, I am trying to find examples of generalized linear models where the posterior $g_{\beta|y} \propto \exp(-f(y;X,\beta) - \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2)$ such that $mI \prec \nabla^2f \prec LI$, and $m,L > 0$. $\beta$ is unknown parameters and prior on $\beta \sim N(0,\frac{1}{\lambda}I)$ for $\lambda > 0$. I know linear model is an example which satisfies above constraints, but I am not able to find other models. I think poison regression does not follow above constraints. Would logistic regression fit above criteria?

Comment: Can you explain in slightly higher detail the function $f$ and the constraint on its second derivative? I'm not familiar with the $f(y : X, \beta$) and $\prec$ notations

Comment: $f(y;X,\beta)$ simlpy denoates $f$ is a function of $y$, $X$ and $\beta$. If $A \succ B$ means $A - B$ is a positive definie matrix.

Comment: @DushyantSahoo the way that your question is expressed is still very concentrated. It is not easy to contemplate what is going on. Do you have a more intuitive explanation of the question?